# BufferedReader gives weird behaviour on different Android versions

Tags: java, android

I am trying to open an existing file, and process it, and save it somewhere else in Android.

```
File in = new File("/sdcard/a.pdf"); // This file exists in the location and has been obtained by using getExternalStorage()
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(in);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

header = br.readLine(); // this gives first line in android 2.3.3 but gives null in android 2.3.6
```

Executing the above code in Android 2.3.3 gives me the header while executing it in Android 2.3.6 gives "null" in the header.

What may be the problem?

Please Help.

Comment: Never hardcode paths. `/sdcard` has been wrong for years. Please use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get the path to the root of external storage.

Comment: actually, I am using getExternalStorageDirectory() for calling it. That is in another file, so for sake of simplicity I wrote that code there. The problem actually exists in br.readLine()

Comment: So you're parsing a PDF!

Comment: not only pdf, it can be any file.

Comment: did you checked with other format files ?

Comment: yes, I have. it works in Android 2.3.3 as I said, what can stop it working in Android 2.3.6 ???

Comment: Sorry if this seems obvious, but... are you sure you're using the same file on both devices?

Comment: yes, no doubt on that.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you explicitly specify the charset to use in each case. At the moment you are relying on the default, which may vary between platforms.

Try the alternative `InputStreamReader` constructor instead:

```
new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8")
```

Comment: OK, but you should always explicitly supply the charset/locale anyway, for safety.